# VB 2013 Embedded resources

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, embedded-resource, 7zip

I just wanted to get clarification on the approach I'm taking with my program. I'm making a program with custom interface for achiving folders. I would like to use 7zip if possible. In the past I have written batch scripts to that use 7zip command line for archiving. If I want to use my VB tool on a system that doesn't have this available, I would like for this to be embedded in my app.

My question is that know how to embed an exe in a VB app, but does this make it immediately available for use in the program no matter where I use it? Or it make the exe available to be deployed somewhere on the station, then I would have to call it from the disk and then possibly delete it when I'm done?

I've done some searching online for similar applications, but am still unsure of how to use embedded files. I'm not looking for example code. Just clarification on whether I can immediately call the exe from within my app, or I embedding just means I can place that file somewhere on the station that I move my app to and then use it? Clarification on this would be most welcome. Thanks!!!

Comment: First, know that there can be legal issues involved in distributing someone else's app/work without attribution.  But mainly, NET 4.5 includes a `ZipFile ` class so that you may not even have to go down that road.  Older NET versions have other file compression methods.  Its a bit easier managing it directly than invoking an external process.  Some of those utilities also provide an API so that you can use it in an app without embedding anything.

Comment: Do not embed, just use a side DLL, which you can package together with your app (for XCOPY). If license requires it, you can also include some license documents there.

Comment: http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html

Comment: Plutonix - Hi again, thanks for all your help so far. 7zip is free to redistribute as far as I'm aware. But if I can invoke a ZipFile class then that sounds like a great alternative. I will look into that as soon as I get a chance. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the link too! I will look into that also. With the SDK it sounds like I will be able to create a 7zip app. That being said, I take it I can just use C# on the VB form?

Comment: Neolisk - Can you explain the DLL scenario briefly and how that might work? Using a DLL I will be able to use my app soley to compress and decompress files? I will do some googling too. Thanks!

Comment: there is a 7zip.DLL which should provide the stuff you need.  If you use the C# version, you should be able to use it from VB with little or no problem.  "free to distribute" does not mean without restriction (see the license) such as attributing them specifically in your license and About Box (specifics vary). to be sure someone specific sees your reply use `@` as in @Neolisk so they do get pinged.

Comment: @Plutonix - Thanks again. I will look into using a DLL and post up my attempts.

Comment: It is not going to work.  The operating system *requires* that DLLs that contain unmanaged code (like 7zip does) are stored in a file on disk.

Comment: For what its worth, I created my own batch file and embedded it into my resources. Then when the program is run, I copy the batch file from my resources to the application's running directory and then call it from there. Then when it is finished, I delete from the same location. So just to answer your original question, you do need to copy it down to the hard drive to use it if it has been embedded in your source code.

Comment: I came across [this item](https://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/) the other day

Comment: @Plutonix. Cheers, perhaps when I am satisfied with this project, I can provide 7z as an alternative using that. You're a great resource man!

Comment: *Software is never completed, only released.*  More likely you will look at this in a month and want to start over using what youve learned to better advantage. Then in 3 months (GoTo Start:).  Only the interval changes.

Comment: @Plutonix Ha, I fully understand that. I can already see two more "releases" this will surely expand as my knowledge grows for sure! Thanks again!